# MySQL Query LEFT JOIN, SUM()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Inventory and InventoryTypes. Inventory has a column for the number of items available, and a column for a foreign key typeID (+ other ones not needed here). InventoryTypes has a column for class (i.e. further classification of the types of inventory), typeName, description and typeID primary key.

**I want to sum the available column grouped by the typeID and then join on the InventoryTypes table where the typeIDs are equal.**

I managed to create the initial SQL statement which works:

```
    SELECT typeID, SUM(available) AS NumberofInventoryPerType FROM Inventory GROUP BY typeID;
```

When I try to use LEFT JOIN for the InventoryTypes table as following:

```
    SELECT typeID, SUM(available) AS NumberofInventoryPerType FROM Inventory GROUP BY typeID
    LEFT JOIN (InventoryTypes ON Inventory.typeID = InventoryTypes.typeID ORDER BY InventoryTypes.descr);
```

**SAMPLE DATA:**

Inventory Table:

**invID - available - typeID**

1     -   10      -   1

2     -   15      -   2

3     -   10      -   1

InventoryTypes Table:

**typeID -   class    - typeName - descr**

1      -  packaging -  box     -   10x10 box

2      -   tools    -  pipette -   0.1 ml pipette

The query should then return:

**typeID -    class   - typeName -    descr       - NumberofInventoryPerType**

1        - packaging  -   box    -  10x10 box     -        20

2        - tools      - pipette  - 0.1 ml pipette -        15

The query does not execute and indicates an error near LEFT JOIN. I only found examples where the initial select query does not have a GROUP BY clause. Is this where my mistake lies? Any help is appreciated

Comment: The `GROUP BY` should be at the end of your  SQL statement, but before the `ORDER BY`  (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: ok. i added sample date and results hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general structure of a SQL query is (note that all sections are optional except SELECT):

```
SELECT columns
FROM block_of_data_like_a_table_or_query
  JOIN another_block_of_data_like_a_table_or_query
  JOIN a_third_block_of_data_like_a_table_or_query
WHERE conditions
GROUP BY columns
ORDER BY columns
```

You can't put your [left] join after a group by; you have to put it in the FROM area

If you want to perform a grouping and then join it to some other table, you group as a subquery:

```
SELECT columns
FROM table
  JOIN (SELECT columns FROM table JOIN table WHERE conditions GROUP BY columns) ON ...

WHERE conditions
GROUP BY columns
ORDER BY columns
```

The overall rule of how an SQL must be structured is thus preserved; a table is a block of data, a query is also (producing) a block of data. Blocks of data must be joined in the FROM area.

In your specific case, do the grouping as a subquery, then join in the result:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT typeID, SUM(available) AS NumberofInventoryPerType FROM Inventory GROUP BY typeID) sumup
  LEFT JOIN
  InventoryTypes it
    ON sumup.typeID = it.typeID
ORDER BY it.descr
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not mix **Group By** with **LEFT JOIN**:

Here is a example for LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

Try to group the result in an extra query.
Use [INTO](http://www.sqlexamples.info/SQL/bsc_save_results.htm) Param to save the result from the first query!

see also [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: I see nothing that speaks against using outer joins and aggregations in the same query. See Caius Jard's answer on how this is done.

Comment: okay a sub-query is also a way: --> subquery in brackets as carius jards suggested 
 JOIN (SELECT columns FROM table JOIN table WHERE conditions GROUP BY columns) ON

Answer (score 0):

Formally (without even trying to understand the meaning of the query)

```
SELECT Inventory.typeID, SUM(Inventory.available) AS NumberofInventoryPerType 
FROM Inventory 
LEFT JOIN InventoryTypes ON Inventory.typeID = InventoryTypes.typeID
GROUP BY Inventory.typeID
ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(InventoryTypes.descr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT it.typeID, SUM(i.available) AS NumberofInventoryPerType
FROM InventoryTypes it LEFT JOIN
     Inventory i
     ON it.typeID = i.typeID
ORDER BY MAX(it.descr);
```

Notes:

- If you want all inventory types, it should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.
- Use table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.